# Check if user is enrolled in specific Moodle course

Tags: moodle

On a Moodle-enabled site, I want to give users some coupons.

I made it to check if the user is logged in, but I also want to check if the current logged in user is enroled in specific course (an array of 3 course IDs).

So far I tried with `$USER->currentcourseaccess` or `$USER-> lastcourseaccess`, but they don't do the trick.

So, how can I check if the current logged in user is enrolled in specific Moodle course?

---

**Edit:** The site uses *Moodle 2*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to first get the course context, and then check your user against the list of enrolled users with a specific role ID in that context (default role ID for Student is 5). Wit h the Moodle 2.0+ API, you can do it without directly querying the database:

```
$context = get_context_instance(CONTEXT_COURSE, $course_id);
$students = get_role_users(5, $context);
```

In Moodle 1.9, you'll need to manually get the stuff from the DB:

- first the `mdl_contexts` table with `contextlevel = CONTEXT_COURSE (CONTEXT_COURSE = 50)` and `instanceid = <id of course>`
- and then `mdl_role_assignments` with `contextid = <first result>` and `roleid = 5`

Comment: Yes, the site uses Moodle 2 [forgot to mention].

Answer (score 7):

I just use this simple 2 line solution (, using course and user id):

```
global $USER;

$context = get_context_instance(CONTEXT_COURSE, $courseid, MUST_EXIST);
$enrolled = is_enrolled($context, $USER->id, '', true);
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: can you please check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46110220/use-moodle-enrol-me-option-in-custom-php-application..if you can help can you please explain..

Answer (score 5):

you can also run this sql command:

```
SELECT c.id AS id, c.fullname,c.shortname, u.username, u.firstname, 
u.lastname, u.email
FROM mdl_role_assignments ra, mdl_user u, mdl_course c, mdl_context cxt
WHERE ra.userid = u.id
AND ra.contextid = cxt.id
AND cxt.contextlevel = 50
AND cxt.instanceid = c.id
AND u.username = 'User_Username'
AND c.shortname = 'Course_Shortname'
AND (roleid =5 OR roleid=3);
```

> this should check if the user with user name 'User_Username' is enrolled in the course with shortname 'Course_Shortname' as student or teacher

hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Enrollment check code snippet :

```
function check_enrollment($username, $course){ 
    global $DB;
    $sql = "SELECT count(*)
            FROM mdl_user_enrolments a,
            mdl_enrol b,
            mdl_user c

            WHERE c.username='$username'
            AND a.userid=c.id
            AND b.courseid=$course
            AND a.enrolid=b.id";
    $n = $DB->count_records_sql($sql);
    if($n==0) {
        //user not enrolled
        return False;
    } elseif($n==1) {
        //user already enrolled
        return True;
    } else { 
        //, bad data ie<Data sanity not maintained>
        add_to_log($course, 'ERROR: check-enrollment', 'Entered into mordor code block');
        return False;
    } 
}
```